# DI, ServiceProvider, abstract parent and Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, service, dependency-injection

I have some problem and little misunderstanding Laravel SP (ServiceProvider). I have abstract class Repository and her Interface:

```
abstract class Repository implements RepositoryInterface {

private $model;
private $parser;

public function __construct() {
    $this->model = new $this->model_name();
} }


interface RepositoryInterface {

public function create(array $attributes);
public function update($id, array $attributes);
public function delete($id);

public function all();
public function find($id);
public function filter(array $parameters, $query=null);
public function query(array $parameters, $query=null); }
```

and some child UserRepository for example:

```
class UserRepository extends Repository implements UserRepositoryInterface {

protected $model_name = "App\Models\User";

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function activation($user_id) {
    return "user";
}

public function deactivation($user_id) {
    return "user";
} }
```

and simple ModelParser class:

```
class ModelParser {

protected $parameters;
protected $model;

public function __construct($model) {
    $this->model = $model;
} }
```

This work fine, but I would pass `ModelParser` as DI in my construct of abstract `Repository` with parameter `$model`. I dont have idea. How should I do it ?

I use it like this:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

private $repository;

public function __construct(UserRepository $repository) {
    $this->repository = $repository;
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's kinda complicated since your `ModelParser` requires a `$model` as it's parameter. And because this `$model` may vary depends on its repository, it will be too complicated if we're trying to resolve it using Laravel [service container binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#binding).

There's an easier approach, we can make the `ModelParser` class's constructor receive an optional `$model` parameter. Then we can add an additional method to set this `$model` property like so:

```
namespace App\Models;

class ModelParser
{
    protected $parameters;
    protected $model;

    // Make $model parameter optional by providing default value.
    public function __construct($model = null) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    // Add setter method for $model.
    public function setModel($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And now you can inject the `ModelParser` into your abstract `Repository` class. Laravel will easily resolve this `ModelParser` parameter

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\ModelParser;
use App\Models\RepositoryInterface;

abstract class Repository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    private $model;
    private $parser;

    // Pass ModelParser instance to your constructor!
    public function __construct(ModelParser $parser)
    {
        $this->model = new $this->model_name();

        // Set the parser's model property.
        $this->parser = $parser->setModel($this->model);
    }

    // Rest of your code.
}
```

And if you're extending the abstract `Repository` class, you still have to pass this `ModelParser` to the constructor like so:

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\ModelParser;
use App\Models\UserRepositoryInterface;

class UserRepository extends Repository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $model_name = "App\Models\User";

    public function __construct(ModelParser $parser)
    {
        parent::__construct($parser);
    }
}
```

Actually, if you're not planning to pass another parameter or perform something else during the class instantiation, you can simply remove the `__construct()` method from `UserRepository` and rely on its parent (the abstract `Repository`).

Hope this help!

Comment: Yes, this help me a lot. I did it in another way but I wanted something with DI. Thank you!